# My question was deleted without explanation and i'm pissed

Tags: discussion, notifications, moderation, moderators

Not closed, deleted. Just like that. I thought it was a valid question, which had already 5+ comments.

So I just tried to delete ALL OF MY QUESTIONS + ANSWERS. Unfortunately someone undeleted my questions so I will have to find another way.

I can't believe the arrogance of some uberuser moderators. So long.

**EDIT:** Ok, you can call me an arrogant looney vandal that can't form complete sentences and you're probably right. However, just deleting someones question, posed with good intentions, and without explaining why or where it went, I call RUDE. you can all downvote me to -32535, that's what I think is the truth. The only explanation i've been given here is: "it was deleted because it was flagged by the system and the community as a low quality post from a new user, and indeed, it was."

Now I don't know what's understood with "A new user" but I've been a member of SU for 4 months. Moreoever, I'm not saying it was not a low quality post. I'm saying you shouldn't just delete someone's post without explanation if it's posted with good intentions. Just CLOSE for being low quality or whatever, so the user knows.

Comment: While I agree that people are getting a bit trigger happy with the delete button (breaking permalinks in the progress. No good!), that's no reason for vandalism.

Answer (score 13):

If you're referring to the question [Is 6 x 2GB DDR3 faster than 2 x 6GB DDR3 RAM ? (dual channel)](https://superuser.com/questions/238660/is-6-x-2gb-ddr3-faster-than-2-x-6gb-ddr3-ram-dual-channel) on Super User, it was deleted because it was flagged by the system **and** the community as a low quality post from a new user, and indeed, it was.

The 5+ comments, of which 2 were yours, were all trying to get more information, which should have been used to improve the question.

It didn't meet any of the basic criteria for asking questions, and you could really have put more effort into it. High quality questions will receive high quality answers, however your question didn't provide any information that could lead to a real answer without it being speculation.

There is a huge drive across the whole Stack Exchange network to improve the level of questions and answers entering the system, and review system was put in place specifically for new user questions.

**Further Investigation**

Your account was also suspended by Ivo for continuing to delete your answers & questions. There is a good chance that you were emailed about this, however I am not sure if the email address on your account is valid.

Comment: If my question was badly formulated, too short or whatever, you could have just said so and I would have immediately edited the question. It was indeed a very short question, yet at the moment I thought it was clear and concise. 'Is 6 x 2 faster then 2 x 6' ... I'm not offended by someone thinking my question isn't clear. I'm offended by someone who just deletes my post without an explanation or anything whatsoever. I think that's just plain arrogant.

Comment: @Run. Honestly, if we commented on every question we close or delete, nothing would ever get done. You overreacted, however; most users post a question on MSE or alternatively email the moderators to ask what's going on, and we will then explain. Your question didn't give enough details for anyone to even make an informed guess of how to answer, based on it simply which is faster?. Honestly, you deleting all your questions solely made the situation worse, rather then any better. Your question was deleted, move on, come up with a better one and ask again. It's honestly not the end of the world.

Comment: @Run CMD: So, you get *one* of your questions deleted (whatever the reason is), then try to delete all your questions and answers in attempt to achieve some childish kind of revenge... and then *someone else* is arrogant. Yeah, right.

Comment: @Goran: If I think I'm right I will fight for it. I'm not after revenge. I'm after justice. What's a user to do ?

Comment: @Run Fight for it sensibly, not like a loony please. You should have posted here long before even considering vandalism.

Comment: I did not email @Run CMD as he clearly deleted his questions on purpose, just to provoke a reaction. I suspended him for 7 days to cool down and make sure he stopped deleting his other questions. If he agrees to stop deleting his questions, I'm happy to lift the suspension

Answer (score 7):

> Not closed, deleted. Just like that. I thought it was a valid question, which had already 5+ comments.

Are you referring to ["Dotfuscator files “Map.0.xml” till “Map.268.xml” take a Gig ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816974/dotfuscator-files-map-0-xml-till-map-268-xml-take-a-gig)? That was deleted by **you yourself** 21 hours ago. If you mean some other question - that shouldn't normally happen. Can you provide a link?

> So I just tried to delete ALL OF MY QUESTIONS + ANSWERS

That is not how this site works, both on a common sense and on the legal level. On the legal level, you have  [licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) your contributions to SO, and you can't just revoke that on a whim. From the [legal page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal):

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network will be licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Overflow the right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services

on a common sense level, you have received help from the community for your questions, and you have no right to destroy those community contributions.

Comment: I'm pissed, not nuts :-) I'm talking about the question "Is 6 x 2 GB DDR3 Faster then 2 x 6GB DDR3 RAM" on the SUPERUSER site. (got redirected here?) I have got NO complaints whatsoever on the STACKOVERFLOW site, those mods are super!

Comment: @Run yeah, I found the link after all (see below). But this should be asked on http://meta.superuser.com/ I think... Interested to see what the discussion yields, from the title it looks like a valid question

Comment: Pekka you're right, seen it too late, sorry. I can't post on meta.superuser.com because my account is suspended ... well, whatever ...

Comment: @Run ah, fair enough. Maybe Jeff will answer here.

Comment: His account was suspended for trying to delete all the content, and not being able to contact him directly.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, I am not seeing anything deleted except for the question you deleted.

We do sometimes arbitrarily delete new questions of *extremely low quality*. This is generally not something you need to worry about if you can form complete sentences and put more than 5 seconds of thought into your questions.

Comment: I think I found it: http://superuser.com/questions/238660/is-6-x-2gb-ddr3-faster-than-2-x-6gb-ddr3-ram-dual-channel but I don't have the rep to look at it

Comment: @Pekka Yep, that's the one he is referring to.