# Proper way to deal with users removing question content

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do when the OP mutilates their own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114803/what-to-do-when-the-op-mutilates-their-own-question)

I came across a question that had the content removed by the author. [Syntax Error in Dice game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080280/syntax-error-in-dice-game)

They basically removed ALL content from the question and replaced it with

```
Closed question
<deleted>
<deleted>
<deleted>
```

Am I in the wrong to revert back to the question so that others that may have a similar issue can know how to over come it or should I have left it as is? I thought if it needed to be closed, a moderator would of closed it, or a close vote would of taken place.

I searched the site but couldn't find any information about best practices when this happens.

Comment: Other related questions: [How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106807/), [What protocol to follow when a user edits his question to “Please delete”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54829/), [User vandalizing his own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104820/), [My question was deleted without explanation and i'm pissed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76875/), [Why do users vandalise their own answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102231/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By all means roll back such edits. If they do it again, flag for moderator attention. Such edits are not appropriate. It destroys possibly valuable content in the question itself or at the very least takes away the context for the answers.

As stated [in the ToS](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.

However, should the author have a particular problem with the question, then he can always ask to be unassociated from that particular question. But deleting the content is never the correct thing to do.